# AR Foundation - Object Tracking for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, tracking, arcore

I'm having trouble finding any information about AR Foundation and Object Tracking. On the documentation, it says Object Tracking is supported, and "to create a reference object library you need to populate the reference object entries with provider-specific assets". Installing ARCore XR Plugin and AR Foundation 4.2 on Unity 2020.3 there're no entries when I try to add reference object. I tried installing AR Kit XR Plugin and now it shows an entry for the AR Kit Reference object. So, it's not possible to use only AR Foundation and AR Core to do object tracking? (I can't use Vuforia and it's suggested to only use ARCore and AR Foundation).

I have to develop an augmented reality app that recognizes an object and displays information panels/images/videos as a guide, and probably will have to use image tracking to do it, if you could link me some tutorials I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

It only works on Ios: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@5.1/manual/features/object-tracking.html

I am also waiting for that.
I don't know why they don't use MediaPipe. You can build a project with these libraries (it's hard to do) in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I am also waiting for Android support. Currently, no way to add a reference object. Same says AR Foundation=>Object Tracking Git page [Samples]: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples#object-tracking